# A function on $\mathbb R^4$ descends to a function on $RP^3$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider the smooth function $f:\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R; (x,y,z,t)\mapsto 4x^2+3y^2+3z^2+t^2.$

1. Show that $f$ descends to a smooth function $g\colon RP^3\to \mathbb R$ such that $g\circ \pi = f$. Here $\pi:\mathbb R^4-\{0\}\to RP^3$ is the canonical projection.
2. Find the critical values of $g$.

I am having difficulty understanding this question. If $g$ is well-defined on $RP^3$ then for $p:=(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb R^4-\{0\}$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$, we should have
$$f(p)=g\circ \pi(p)=g\circ\pi(\alpha p)=f(\alpha p)=\alpha^2 f(p).$$
But this cannot hold for any non-zero $\alpha$.

Comment: This functions satisfies $f(\lambda X) = \lambda^2 f(X)$ so it *does not* induce a function on the quotient. Maybe the exercise asks about its restriction to the unit sphere that indeed is invariant under the antipodal map?

Comment: Thanks @Didier for your comment. I though so too (that $f$ should be over a sphere), but, sadly, the exercise is as stated. It came from an exam bank so I thought it was unlikely that it is incorrect. In case $f$ is defined over a sphere, the question becomes much easier.

Comment: Then I can't really say much more than my previous comment! Exercises sheets often have typos and false statement though

Comment: @Didier Thanks a lot  :-). Should I write down the answer for $f$ on a sphere or delete the question?

Comment: Perhaps they meant $f(x,y,z,t)=\frac{4x^2+3y^2+3z^2+t^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2}$ defined on $\Bbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}$. The denominator cancels out the homogeneity of the numerator, so this descends to the quotient $\Bbb{R}P^3$. The restriction of this map to $S^3$ is the same as the restriction of your $f$ to $S^3$, so as mentioned by the previous comment, the map on the sphere descends to the quotient. But yes, as stated, the question is meaningless.

Comment: As a homogeneous polynomial of degree two, $f$ should not descend to a smooth function on $\mathbb RP^3$ but to a smooth section of a line bundle that is usually denoted by $\mathcal O(2)$. But I don't think that for such sections there is a well defined notion of critical values. Probably the idea of @peek-a-boo is what is really meant with the exercise (for this, the critical values are interesting).